# Windows - Error: Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: node.js, node-deasync

Stuck with strange error with deasync module.

trace:

```
E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:91
  throw err
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\build\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\build\Debug\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\build\Release\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\out\Debug\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\Debug\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\out\Release\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\Release\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\build\default\deasync.node
 тЖТ E:\development\oxy\node_modules\deasync\compiled\8.2.1\win32\x64\deasync.node
```

Tried npm i -g node-gyp and node-gyp rebuild but wihout any luck
What I`ve missed? How can I solve it and what cause this bug?

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Can you show me full logs? Are you sure that version of `deasync` you are currently using supports the version of Node you are working with?

Comment: If error only occur when you run jest. See here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1694#issuecomment-257113870

Answer (score 3):

You may need to rebuild your modules. This command fixed it for me:

`npm rebuild`